# ajax error during drupal installation

Tags: ajax, installation

I'm installing drupal 7 on my windows 7 machine and I use WAMP. Thing is, at the end of the drupal installation I had the following error:

> An AJAX HTTP request terminated abnormally. Debugging information
>   follows. Path:
>   http://localhost:8080/install.php?profile=standard&locale=en&id=1&op=do
>   StatusText: ResponseText: ReadyState: 4

Has anybody ever seen this during the installation process? Do yo  guys have any idea what it could be?

One thing I should mention is that my localhost is localhost:8080, that's where I commenced the drupal installation, but in phpmyadmin when I am asked:

> In the drop-down menu beside the Host field, select Local.

I'm pretty sure it says localhost only.
COuld it be that?

thanks

Comment: All the error message tells us is that the installer AJAX request blew up. It could be something DB related (usually connectivity problems are caught before the installer is started), it could be something else. You should look through Apache/PHP error logs for entries that match up to the above failed request.